# how to get to a text in a div to console log that test in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get to a text in a div to make a var == that text. 
my code is. the reason i cannot make this var just say var currentplayer = "darthvader"
is because the name in this div will change depending on what character they choose. i hope i didnt make this confusing by the way i have asked this.

```
<div class = " character .player-selected">
    <p class = " character-name>darthvader</p>
```

jquery

```
 var characters = [{
        name: "DarthVader",
        health: 120,
        attack: 8,
        enemyattackback: 15,
        imgURL: "assests/images/darth_vader.jpg"
    },

    {
        name: "StormTrooper",
        health: 100,
        attack: 14,
        enemyattackback: 5,
        imgURL: "assests/images/stormtrooper.jpg"
    },

    {
        name: "LukeSkywalker",
        health: 150,
        attack: 8,
        enemyattackback: 20,
        imgURL: "assests/images/Luke_Skywalker.jpg"

    },

    {
        name: "Yoda",
        health: 180,
        attack: 7,
        enemyattackback: 20,
        imgURL: "assests/images/yoda.jpg"
    }
];
var selectedCharacter;
var enemy;
var fighter;
var gamestart = false
var chooseopp = false

console.log(characters[0]);
console.log(characters[1]);
console.log(characters[2]);
console.log(characters[3]);

// start the game with a loop that sends the 4 character in the object to a div
$(document).ready(function() {

    function startgame() {
        $.each(characters, function(index, character) {
            var characterDiv = $('<div>').addClass('character');
            var characterName = $('<p>').addClass("character-name").text(character.name);
            var characterImg = $("<img>").addClass("character-img").attr('src',
                character.imgURL);;
            var characterHealth = $('<p>').addClass('character-health').text(character.health);
            characterDiv.append(characterName, characterImg, characterHealth).appendTo('.Character')
        })




        $('.character').one("click", function() {
            $(this).addClass('.player-selected').appendTo('.player');
            $('.Character').children()
                .off('click')
                .addClass("enemy")
                .on('click', newEnemySelected);

        })

        function newEnemySelected() {
            $(this).appendTo('.fighter');
            $('.Character').children().off("click").hide();
            $('.btn').on("click", attack);
            //move the selected enemy to defender div
            //turn off or disable other enemies
            //enable the attack button to handle logic 
        }

        function attack() {
            var currentPlayer = $('character .player-selected').find('p').text()
            console.log(currentPlayer)
                //take health from enemy by the attack amount
                //to check if player is dead
                //then enemy will counter attack
                // check char. for his health
                //
        }


    };
    startgame()
```

Comment: Does my solution works for u?

Comment: so i have to go thru the first div

Comment: i have tried $('.player-selected').find('.character-name').text() also. but it will console.log blank. i have to go thru the .player-selected. because of the rest of the jquery and what it is doing

Comment: I've edited my post, check it!

Comment: i tried that and it comes up blank still.

Comment: ill post all my jquery

Comment: so i just added my jquery code

Comment: Delete `.` dot from `.player-selected` to make it look like `player-selected`.

Comment: i just tried that and it still just shows blank and will not show the name. i am not sure what is going on here

Comment: i just got it had to to the div that player-selected was in. thanks for all your help

Comment: I have upvoted your question, you now have 16 rep points so you are able to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch an element with `jQuery` marker, then use `html()` function to get the `innerHTML` value of the element.

```js
var name = $('.character-name').html();

console.log(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" character .player-selected">
<p class="character-name">darthvader</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it with `.text()` like so:

```js
var currentplayer = $('.player-selected').find('.character-name').text();
console.log(currentplayer)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "character player-selected">
    <p class = "character-name">darthvader</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried  $('.player-selected').find('.character-name').text() also. but it will console.log blank. i have to go thru the .player-selected. because of the rest of the jquery and what it is doing.

Comment: @willis You have a `.` inside the class name of the div. Remove it.